# Printing the value from a memory address in C++ as hex

Tags: c++, hex

I'm trying to make a program that takes in an integer value and then prints out the value of each of the four bytes in hex. So for 255 it should print out FF 00 00 00. This is what my code is looking like so far.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int num;
    cout << "Enter an integer" << endl;
    cin >> num;

    int* p = &num;
    unsigned char* q = (unsigned char*)p;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cout<< hex <<*(int*)(q+i) << " ";
    }

}
```

When I enter 255 it prints `ff cc000000 cccc0000 cccccc00` What are the c's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `cout` statement, you are casting `(q+i)` itself to an `int*` pointer and then dereferencing it to get an `int` value.  That is wrong, because `(q+i)` does not point at an `int`, and dereferencing it as such will exceed the bounds of `num` into surrounding memory when `i > 0`.

You need to instead dereference `(q+i)` as-is to get the `unsigned char` it actually points to, and then cast THAT value to an [`unsigned`] `int` (or at least to an [`unsigned`] `short`) when printing it:

```
cout << hex << static_cast<int>(*(q+i)) << " ";
```

Also, an `int` is not always 4 bytes on all systems, so you should not hard-code the size, use `sizeof(int)` instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(num); i++)
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/4nyoAt)

Answer (score 3):

The `CC`s are the uninitialized stack memory tag, set by [Visual C++ in debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations).

Note that you also a strict aliasing violation at `(int*)(q+i)`.

What you *probably* wanted is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num;
    cout << "Enter an integer" << endl;
    cin >> num;

    unsigned char* q = (unsigned char*)&num;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cout << hex << (int)q[i] << " ";
    }

}
```